# Filtering using dplyr but tell R to omit certain columns from filter

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am trying to filter data to remove columns where any cell has a value of less than 10 but I want to omit some columns from the filter (i.e. The elevation and station columns which I need). I can get it to remove all columns where the value is less than 10 using the first line of code and I think I need something like the second to get it to work but I am not quite there, can anyone help?

Thanks

```
#Remove any species that don't exceed 10% abundance in at least 1 sample
transects1<-transects %>% 
  keep(~ any(. >= 10))


transects1<-transects %>%
  filter( if_any(-contains("."), ~ (.>=10)) )

## Data

structure(list(Transect = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B"), Station = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L), Elevation = c(2.528, 1.844, 1.549, 1.335, 
1.015, 1.006), H.w = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100), E.m = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), T.i = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0), T.s = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), T.ir = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S.l = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), P.m = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), H.m = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Q.sp = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), M.f = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), E.spp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), H.spp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), A.spp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    C.spp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), M.l = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), C.i = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Cr.spp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), N.spp = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Am.spp = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), S.m = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), G.spp = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), P.n.spp = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You need this:? `df %>%
  filter(if_any(contains("."), ~.>=10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to `select` columns with logical conditions, we should use the `where` selection helper with `where(condition)`. We can hard code the desired columns to add them later.

```
df %>% select(c(Station, Elevation), where(~any(.x < 10)))

# A tibble: 6 × 24
  Station Elevation   H.w   E.m   T.i   T.s  T.ir   S.l   P.m   H.m  Q.sp
    <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1      2.53     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2       2      1.84     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
3       1      1.55     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4       3      1.34     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5       3      1.01     0     0   100     0     0     0     0     0     0
6       4      1.01   100     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
# ℹ 13 more variables: M.f <dbl>, E.spp <dbl>, H.spp <dbl>, A.spp <dbl>,
#   C.spp <dbl>, M.l <dbl>, C.i <dbl>, Cr.spp <dbl>, N.spp <dbl>,
#   Am.spp <dbl>, S.m <dbl>, G.spp <int>, P.n.spp <dbl>
```